# Using left join and keep value of left table ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database where the first one has related values of the second one. Just like this:

table "people"

```
ID |    NAME   | SCHOOL
-------------------------
1  | john      | 2
2  | fred      | 1
3  | maria     | 3
```

table "school"

```
ID |   NAME  
-------------------------
1  | first school
2  | second school
3  | third school
```

Ok.
I'm trying to make a select in "people" table and get the "SCHOOL" number replaced by "school" table related id.

So I did this:

```
"SELECT * FROM people A LEFT JOIN school B ON A.school = B.id"
```

That's ok!

But If I have to get the "people" ID value in this return, it will be replaced by "school" table ID value.

How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of * use A.ID as people_id, A.NAME as people_name, B.ID as school_id, B.NAME as  school_name

Comment: You only need a left join if you are uncertain that a person ever went to any school, in which case it will return all the people regardless of whether they went to school (null in the school column of the people table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are learning SQL, learn to list all the columns you want.  Explicitly:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, s.name as school_name
FROM 
     people p LEFT JOIN
     school s
     ON p.school = s.id;
```

Notes:

- The table aliases are abbreviations for the table names.  This makes the query much easier to follow.
- A `LEFT JOIN` is not really needed here, but you are using it.
- `s.name` could be aliased (`s.name as school_name`) to distinguish it from the person's name.

Comment: a.school -> p.school?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, people.id FROM people A LEFT JOIN school B ON A.school = B.id

use * and table.id
```